# prove that a composite function is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity, proof-writing, piecewise-continuity

For these functions:

$$h(x)= \begin{cases} 
      e^{-x} & x\geq  0 \\
      \sqrt{|x|} & x<0 \\
   \end{cases}$$

$$g(x)=(x−4)(x+1)^{2}$$

So obviously h(x) is discontinuous at x =0, but how do I prove that **h(g(x)) is continuous**? By the continuity definition you cannot prove h(g(x)) is continuous (since h(x) is discontinuous itself). I think a good place to start is to prove that g(x) is continuous, it is trivial how to do that. But what do I do next? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the product of continuous functions, $g(x)$ is continuous everywhere.

As you indicated, $h(x)$ is only discontinuous at $x=0$.

Thus $h[g(x)]$ is only discontinuous when $g(x) = 0$.

Thus $h[g(x)]$ is only discontinuous when $x = 4$ or $x = -1$.

Comment: Sorry for this simple question, but how did you arrive at the x = 4 or x =-1 is discontinuous? I know that g(x) has this roots, but how does the composite function have it?

Comment: @SneakAttr The composite function $h \circ g$ does **not** have roots at $x=4$ or $x=-1$.  The graph of $h(x)$, **is** discontinuous at $h(0),~$ however.  If (for example) $x=4$, then $g(x) = 0$, so $h[g(x)] = h(0)$, which is the point where the function $h(x)$ is discontinuous.  More explicitly, $h[g(4)] = h(0).$